# Show a Client Alert After the codebehind has been processed. ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, alert

I have this code behind in my ASP.NET 4 Web Forms app:

```
Protected Sub BTNSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNSave.Click

   If saveOnDB() Then
      showOkAlert()
   Else
      showErrorAlert()
   End If
End Sub
```

I need to show a client alert when something done in the code behind has gone OK or an error has happened. Any idea?

I haved tied `Response.Write("<script>alert('Successfully added');</script>")` but this never works and even creates an error in the browser's console: "Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed."

Also I don't use `OnClientClick` because it triggers the javascript before the codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar. I've hacked some working code to simplify it as an example for your particular use:

```
    private void RegisterJavascriptForUpdatePanelExample(UpdatePanel myUpdatePanel, string myMessage)
    {
        const string JAVASCRIPT_TEMPLATE = "javascript: jQuery(function($) {{ alert({0}); }});";
        const string SCRIPT_KEY_TEMPLATE = "KeyForRegisterJavascriptForModalPopup_{0}";
        string scriptkey, scriptstr;

        scriptkey = string.Format(SCRIPT_KEY_TEMPLATE, myUpdatePanel.ClientID);
        scriptstr = string.Format(JAVASCRIPT_TEMPLATE, myMessage);
        ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(myUpdatePanel, myUpdatePanel.GetType(), scriptkey, scriptstr, true);
    }
```

In this example, a simple JavaScript alert() is called to display your message, like this:

```
RegisterJavascriptForUpdatePanelExample("A-OK!");
```

Of particular interest is the ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock function. There are several variations of this, depending if the JavaScript code should be embedded and executed within an UpdatePanel, or when the page loads, or other situations. It can be kind of confusing to decide which function is needed, but it's just what you need.

Comment: In my example, I included a call to jQuery in JAVASCRIPT_TEMPLATE. Without jQuery, it would simply be: "javascript: alert({0});"